# Convert the grid background to image through code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to convert the grid background to image through code behind,how to do this-

I have tried this-

```
ImageBrush gridBackground = (ImageBrush)(((Grid)sender).Background);
System.Windows.Controls.Image gridBackImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
gridBackImage.Source = gridBackground.ImageSource;
```

it is giving error-

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush'.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `gridBackImage` which is image? Why not use imagebrush?

Comment: Please tell how to handle above exception i posted with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
  Image image = new Image();
  image.Source = new BitmapImage(
      new Uri(
         "pack://application:,,,/MyClassLibrary;/Images/Image1.jpg"));
  myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
  Grid grid = (Grid)sender;
  grid.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: i want to convert grid background to image not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

I feel you need to clarify your requirements more, because what you might be attempting might be a wrong approach. I feel you haven't set any image to the background of the grid but only a color.

So setting background to a color it will return an SolidColorBrush and not an Image, i.e. ImageBrush.

If you have set it to an Image background then your code will work fine. But the question is what is that you are intending to do with `gridBackImage`? because I feel we are converting it to something which is not necessary. If you say what you intent to do it would be better to solve.

```
var grid = sender as Grid;
Image gridBackImage =new Image();
gridBackImage.Source = grid.Background.ImageSource;
```

Comment: rambo please check the answer which i posted is right or not? as now it is not throwing that exception

Comment: I understand @Saritha.S.R's answer will work without an error. But I am still not clear what you would like to achieve? If you want to set the Grid with an Image or get the Image from the grid which has already been set?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily be acheived in the xaml by adding the following code in the grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>  
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProject;component/Images/bg.png"/>     
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Left for you to do, is adding a folder to the solution called 'Images' and adding an existing file to your new 'Images' folder, in this case called 'bg.png'

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reverse Saritha.S.R's answer like:

```
ImageBrush myBrush = (ImageBrush)(((Grid)sender).Background);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = myBrush.ImageSource;
```

Is that what you're after?

**Edit**:

Your edit:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to type System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush'.
```

Indicates that you don't really have an image set as background. You need something like:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="YourBackgroundImage.jpg"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Or in code behind:

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourProject;component/YourBackgroundImage.jpg"));
myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
yourGrid.Background = myBrush;
```

For this to work. You simply can't get an image from a SolidColorBrush

Comment: Please check i have already edited my question,consisting of same code which you posted but the error now is-Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush'.

Comment: Please tell what should i manipulate in the above code i posted as question,i have to do everything with code behind only not xaml

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Backround to ImageBrush instead of Image.

```
ImageBrush img = (Grid_Image.Background as ImageBrush);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Image Background is set as ImageBrush, like

```
   <Grid Height="300" Width="100" x:Name="Grid_Image">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/SmallLogo.scale-100.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
```

Then you can cast in code behind as mentioned by you.

```
    ImageBrush im = ((ImageBrush)(((Grid)sender).Background); 
    Image gridBackImage =new Image();
    gridBackImage.Source = im.ImageSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved,My code is-
 ImageBrush gridBackground;

```
        if (((Grid)sender).Children.Count > 0)
        {
            gridBackground = (ImageBrush)(((Grid)sender).Background);
            System.Windows.Controls.Image gridBackImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            gridBackImage.Source = gridBackground.ImageSource;

            ImageCar.Source = gridBackImage.Source;
        }
```